Call own GET method inside spring unit-test using reactive WebClient
We are getting this error

org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException

in production environment in a low percentage of cases. The system is spring boot v 3.0.5 with webflux.
Found solution is to increase buffer size:
@Bean
    fun restWebClient(webClientBuilder: WebClient.Builder): WebClient = webClientBuilder
            .clientConnector(ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create(ConnectionProvider.newConnection())))
            <...filtrations...>
            .codecs { codecs -> codecs.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(1024 * bufferSize)}
            .build()

I want to write unit test which is going to reproduce this error by calling test endpoint. Then - assert that we getting exception on response which is more than 1024 * bufferSize. And opposite - no error and 200 on small response.
Here is how am trying to solve the problem:
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.AutoConfigureWebTestClient
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.http.MediaType
import org.springframework.test.context.TestPropertySource
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController

@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@TestPropertySource("/application-test.properties")
class RestServiceConfigurationTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var webClient: WebClient

    @RestController
    class DummyController {

        @GetMapping(path = ["/the-big-response"], produces = [MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE])
        fun test(): String {
            return "some long string, more than 512 kb..."
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun testWebClientBuffer() {
        val out = webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/the-big-response")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(String::class.java)
                .block()
        print(out)

    }
}

But I now get this error:

org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientRequestException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:80
at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below:
Assembly trace from producer
[reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied] :
reactor.core.publisher.Mono.error(Mono.java:314)
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.wrapException(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*________Mono.error ⇢
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.wrapException(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
*Mono.onErrorResume ⇢
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:105)
|             Mono.map ⇢
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:106)
|           checkpoint ⇢ Request to GET /the-big-response [DefaultWebClient]
|   Mono.switchIfEmpty ⇢
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$10(DefaultWebClient.java:446)
|        Mono.doOnNext ⇢
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$10(DefaultWebClient.java:450)
|       Mono.doOnError ⇢
at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$10(DefaultWebClient.java:451)
|      Mono.doOnCancel ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$10(DefaultWebClient.java:452)
|   Mono.doOnTerminate ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$10(DefaultWebClient.java:456)
|    Mono.contextWrite ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.lambda$exchange$10(DefaultWebClient.java:457)
*_Mono.deferContextual ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultRequestBodyUriSpec.exchange(DefaultWebClient.java:434)
|         Mono.flatMap ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.DefaultWebClient$DefaultResponseSpec.bodyToMono(DefaultWebClient.java:556)
Original Stack Trace:
at app//org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.lambda$wrapException$9(ExchangeFunctions.java:136)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoErrorSupplied.subscribe(MonoErrorSupplied.java:55)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:234)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:234)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onError(FluxPeekFuseable.java:234)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onError(MonoNext.java:93)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyMain.onError(MonoFlatMapMany.java:204)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onError(SerializedSubscriber.java:124)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.whenError(FluxRetryWhen.java:225)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenOtherSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:274)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.onError(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:139)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.maybeOnError(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:326)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.onNext(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:211)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:117)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor.drain(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:471)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.SinkManyEmitterProcessor$EmitterInner.drainParent(SinkManyEmitterProcessor.java:615)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxPublish$PubSubInner.request(FluxPublish.java:602)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.request(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:162)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch$FluxConcatMapNoPrefetchSubscriber.request(FluxConcatMapNoPrefetch.java:336)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals$ContextWriteRestoringThreadLocalsSubscriber.request(FluxContextWriteRestoringThreadLocals.java:162)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.Operators$DeferredSubscription.request(Operators.java:1717)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onError(FluxRetryWhen.java:192)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201)
at app//reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect$ClientTransportSubscriber.onError(HttpClientConnect.java:311)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoCreate$DefaultMonoSink.error(MonoCreate.java:201)
at app//reactor.netty.resources.NewConnectionProvider$DisposableConnect.onError(NewConnectionProvider.java:154)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.secondError(MonoFlatMap.java:241)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onError(MonoFlatMap.java:315)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:106)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:198)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.MonoError.subscribe(MonoError.java:53)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:4485)
at app//reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:103)
at app//reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.tryFailure(TransportConnector.java:587)
at app//reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.setFailure(TransportConnector.java:541)
at app//reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.lambda$doConnect$7(TransportConnector.java:265)
at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:590)
at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:583)
at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:559)
at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:492)
at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:636)
at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:629)
at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:118)
at app//io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.fulfillConnectPromise(AbstractNioChannel.java:321)
at app//io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:337)
at app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
at app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
at app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at app//io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at app//io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at app//io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base@17.0.9/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.block(Mono.java:1710)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:727)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:156)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:147)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:86)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:103)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:86)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:217)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:213)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:138)
at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy5.stop(Unknown Source)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: no further information: /127.0.0.1:80
Suppressed: The stacktrace has been enhanced by Reactor, refer to additional information below:
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.MonoError] :
reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:94)
reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.tryFailure(TransportConnector.java:587)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError ⇢ at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector$MonoChannelPromise.tryFailure(TransportConnector.java:587)
*__________________________Mono.onErrorResume ⇢ at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.lambda$connect$6(TransportConnector.java:166)
*________________________________Mono.flatMap ⇢ at reactor.netty.transport.TransportConnector.connect(TransportConnector.java:165)
*_________________________________Mono.create ⇢ at reactor.netty.resources.NewConnectionProvider.acquire(NewConnectionProvider.java:64)
*________________________________Mono.create ⇢ at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:210)
|                             Mono.retryWhen ⇢ at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientConnect$MonoHttpConnect.subscribe(HttpClientConnect.java:275)
*_____________________________Flux.concatMap ⇢ at reactor.util.retry.RetrySpec.lambda$generateCompanion$6(RetrySpec.java:360)
|                           Flux.onErrorStop ⇢ at reactor.util.retry.RetrySpec.lambda$generateCompanion$6(RetrySpec.java:379)
*________________________Flux.deferContextual ⇢ at reactor.util.retry.RetrySpec.generateCompanion(RetrySpec.java:357)
*________________________Mono.flatMapMany ⇢ at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientFinalizer.responseConnection(HttpClientFinalizer.java:102)
|                                  Flux.next ⇢ at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector.connect(ReactorClientHttpConnector.java:119)
|                            Mono.doOnCancel ⇢ at org.springframework.http.client.reactive.ReactorClientHttpConnector.connect(ReactorClientHttpConnector.java:120)
|                           Mono.doOnRequest ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:103)
|                            Mono.doOnCancel ⇢ at org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.ExchangeFunctions$DefaultExchangeFunction.exchange(ExchangeFunctions.java:104)
Original Stack Trace:
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:946)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:337)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:334)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:776)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:724)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:650)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:562)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

Is there any possibility to reproduce error in a similar way, using real webClient (not a mock by Mockito)?

Have you read the error? You are trying to run on localhost and connect to port 80, which I doubt is where your application is running, generally it is 8080.

@M.Deinum yes the application is indeed configured to run on 8080 port. I tryed something like this .uri("http://localhost:8080/the-big-response"), but it results with  same error  Connection refused: no further information: localhost/127.0.0.1:8080

Is your application actually started on 8080 (that should be in your log output). Also is your controller even detected?
